# Keep getting Error about undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysqli

I try to show the user country and field that saved in the database by using the following code but I keep getting this error that said

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\LIVE TAG\custom_import.php on line 26

> Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\xampp\htdocs\LIVE TAG\custom_import.php on line 26

> Notice: Undefined index: field in C:\xampp\htdocs\LIVE TAG\custom_import.php on line 35

> Notice: Undefined index: field in C:\xampp\htdocs\LIVE TAG\custom_import.php on line 35

and also here is the before and next side of the code

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "uni";
///////////

//Filter data from here so we can search the exact column that we want to

$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$country = '';
$field = '';
$qu = "SELECT DISTINCT field FROM csv ORDER BY field ASC";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM csv ORDER BY Country ASC";
$statement = $connect->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetch_all(); // LINE 22
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $country .= '<option value="' . $row['country'] . '">' . $row['country'] . '</option>'; //LINE 26
}
$field = '';
$state = $connect->prepare($qu);
$state->execute();
$res = $state->fetchAll();
foreach ($res as $row) {
    $field .= '<option value="' . $row['field'] . '">' . $row['field'] . '</option>'; //LINE 35
}
//rest of the code
```

Comment: You need to call `fetch_all()` on the result not the statement (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: you probably need to name your fields in the query like `SELECT DISTINCT field as distinct_field FROM csv ORDER BY field ASC` and then get it `$row['distinct_field']` (Same for the other query)

Comment: @AlonEitan I already red that one doesn't help

Comment: @AlonEitan your solution doesn't working on my code .:(

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least three problems in your code.

1. `fetch_all()` is a method of `mysqli_result` not `mysqli_stmt`. You need to get the result from the statement first.

   ```
   $res = $result = $statement->get_result();
   $result = $res->fetch_all();
   // or in a single line
   $result = $statement->get_result()->fetch_all();
   ```
2. You are trying to access associative array in your `foreach` loop, but `fetch_all()` returns by default a numerical array. You need to ask for associative array.

   ```
   $result = $statement->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   ```
3. It's `fetch_all()` not `fetchAll()`. You are mixing PDO and mysqli here.